# Use namespace in Typescript

Tags: typescript, namespaces

Is there any alternative for `using namespace` in TypeScript? Here I have some file with namespaces and interfaces:

```
declare namespace NamespaceA {

    export interface IClassA { }

    export namespace NamespaceB {

        export interface IClassB { }

        export namespace NamespaceC {

            export interface IClassC1 { }
            export interface IClassC2 { }
            export interface IClassC3 { }

        }
    }
}
```

I would like use `IClassC1`, `IClassC2` and `IClassC3` in another file:

```
class ClassA implements NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.IClassC1 {  }
class ClassB implements NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.IClassC2 {  }
class ClassC implements NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.IClassC3 {  }
```

Write so long names are not very nice. So I created own type for each interface:

```
type IClassC1 = NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.IClassC1
type IClassC2 = NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.IClassC2
type IClassC2 = NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.IClassC2

class ClassA implements IClassC1 {  }
class ClassB implements IClassC2 {  }
class ClassC implements IClassC3 {  }
```

But is there any better way? For example:

```
using namespace NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC

class ClassA implements IClassC1 {  }
class ClassB implements IClassC2 {  }
class ClassC implements IClassC3 {  }
```

Comment: how about using modules ? Those have better import syntax

Comment: For the frontend, use a bundler like webpack. Thanks to the bundler, you'll be able to use ES6 modules. Then [do not use namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing) at all.

Comment: As Paleo mentioned above do not use namespaces.